# extracting bits from NSData bytes

Tags: ios, nsdata

I would like to extract all the bits in the following bits from NSData byte :

status Data byte : <0011...

Result turns all are 0000 0000 0000 0000  . Could you please tell me how to ?

```
                NSData *aData = [valueData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]; //16 bit status

                status= [self bitsToInt:aData];

                NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", status];     

 int value = [aString intValue];
                NSlog(@"sadasd value : ,%d" ,value );

                unsigned thbit0 = (1 << 0) & value;
                unsigned thbit1 = (1 << 1) & value;
                unsigned thbit2 = (1 << 2) & value;
                unsigned thbit3 = (1 << 3) & value;
                unsigned thbit4 = (1 << 4) & value;
                unsigned thbit5 = (1 << 5) & value;
                unsigned thbit6 = (1 << 6) & value;
                unsigned thbit7 = (1 << 7) & value;
                unsigned thbit8 = (1 << 8) & value;
                unsigned thbit9 = (1 << 9) & value;
                unsigned thbit10 = (1 << 10) & value;
                unsigned thbit11= (1 << 11) & value;
                unsigned thbit12 = (1 << 12) & value;
```

..

```
- (int) bitsToInt : (NSData *) valueDa  {
    uint8_t * bytePtr = (uint8_t  * )[valueDa bytes];

    int high = bytePtr[1] >= 0 ? bytePtr[1] : 256 + bytePtr[1];
    int low = bytePtr[0] >= 0 ? bytePtr[0] : 256 + bytePtr[0];
    return low | (high << 8);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to work with bit string instead of integer values with additional bit extracting.

Here is simple decoder:

```
- (NSString *)getBitsFromData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    const uint8_t *bytes = [data bytes];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        uint8_t byte = bytes[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            ((byte >> j) & 1) == 0 ? [result appendString:@"0"] : [result appendString:@"1"];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
NSString *test = @"test";
NSLog(@"%@", [self getBitsFromData:[test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]);
```

Result:

```
2015-07-29 11:37:31.768 Test[18342:9947704] 00101110101001101100111000101110
```

Comment: I need to extract their individual bits inside the NSDat a , not converting the Strings . What does it used for ?

Comment: This allows you to work with individual bytes easy. You could access each byte you need by index without binary logic operations and shifting.